# sinch verification method not showing in swift 3.0 and xcode 8.0

Tags: swift3, xcode8, sinch, sinch-verification

We are using sinch verification by pods with swift 3.0 and xcode 8.0 . I want to call `initiate()` and `verifyCode()` methods but compiler show `value of type SINVerification? has no member` I have import `import SinchVerification`and written below code :-

```
let region:String = SINDeviceRegion.currentCountryCode()
        let phoneNumber:SINPhoneNumber?
        do {

             try phoneNumber = SINPhoneNumberUtil().parse("xxxxxxxxxx", defaultRegion: region)

            let phoneNumberInE164:String = SINPhoneNumberUtil().formatNumber(phoneNumber!, format: SINPhoneNumberFormat.E164)
           let verification = SINVerification.smsVerification(withApplicationKey: "965010f3-bb37-4356-82ba-fea0452377d9", phoneNumber: phoneNumberInE164) as? SINVerification
            verification.initiate { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
                //handle outcome
                if (success){
                    print("successfully requested phone verification")

                } else {

                    print(error?.localizedDescription)

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should look like this

```
  let verification = SMSVerification(applicationKey:"<APP KEY>", phoneNumber: phoneNumberInE164)
    verification.initiate { (result: InitiationResult, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // handle outcome
    }
```

Not sure why cast to SINVerification, but i think the error is that you have result as a bool but its a InitiationResult

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I am using 2.0.3 version of sinch

Comment: `let verification = SMSVerification(applicationKey:applicationKey, phoneNumber: phoneNumberInE164)` **//this line show error :-  "use of unresolved identifier 'SMSVerfication' "**
            `verification.initiate { (result: InitiationResult, error: NSError?) -> Void in` **// this line show error :-  "use of undeclared type 'initiationResult' "**
                // handle outcome
           `}`
@cjensen